# Rails query] difference between joins and includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-activerecord

`@teachers = User.joins(:students).where("student_id IS NOT NULL")`

The above works, the below doesn't.

`@teachers = User.includes(:students).where("student_id IS NOT NULL")`

As far as I understand, joins and includes should both bring the same result with different performance. According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html), you use `includes` to load associated records of the objects called by Model, where `joins` to simply add two tables together. Using `includes` can also prevent the `N+1 queries`.

First question: why does my second line of code not work?

Second question: should anyone always use `includes` in a case similar to above?

Comment: what do you mean by does not work?

Comment: Check this out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use joins when you want to query against the joined model. This is doing an inner join between your tables.

Includes is when you want to eager load the associated model to the end result. 
This allows you to call the association on any of the results without having to again do the db lookup.
You cannot query against a model that is loaded via includes. If you want to query against it you must use joins( you can do both! )

Comment: Thanks for the point about not being able to query against an included only item.

Comment: It's not completely true now, you can run conditions in join queries now: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Comment: This is incorrect, you can certainly do queries agains the model that is loaded using "references".